# Receiving an error when trying to install git on RHEL8 box

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, rpm

I created a new EC2 on AWS, using RHEL 8. I try to do `sudo yum install git`

But I get back this error:

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:39 ago on Sat 29 May 2021 08:22:36 PM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libnsl.so.1()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both glibc-2.17-322.el7_9.x86_64 and glibc-2.28-151.el8.x86_64
  - package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 requires /usr/bin/perl, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 requires perl(strict), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 requires perl(vars), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 requires perl(lib), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 requires perl(File::Basename), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 requires perl(warnings), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 requires perl(File::stat), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 requires perl(File::Copy), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 requires perl(File::Find), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package git-1.8.3.1-23.el7_8.x86_64 requires perl >= 5.008, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package NetworkManager-cloud-setup-1:1.30.0-7.el8.x86_64 requires libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.25)(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - problem with installed package NetworkManager-cloud-setup-1:1.30.0-7.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Anyone know how I can get around this error?

I try to fix it via `sudo yum install git --allowerasing`, but that gives the below error.

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:06:53 ago on Sat 29 May 2021 08:22:36 PM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: systemd-udev
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
[ec2-user@puppet GPGKEYS]$ sudo yum install git --allowerasing --nobest
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:11 ago on Sat 29 May 2021 08:22:36 PM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: systemd-udev
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Comment: For some reason you are adding a RHEL7/CentOS7 package to a RHEL8 installation. You'll have to provide more information on the changes you did to get this.

Answer (score 0):

You can always install the Fedora epel repos.

Not sure if you are able to deviate from RHEL itself, but just throwing it out there.

sudo yum install epel-release