# Can I install EL7 version of a package in RHEL 8?

Tags: rhel, mysql

My specific query concerns the mysql package; in our corporate directory we have the EL7 version downloaded for mysql 8.0; can this be installed on RHEL8? Please advise.

TIA

Vinod

Comment: Probably not due to dependency issues.  You should install the packages that were build for RHEL8.    Is there some specific reason why you need the EL7 version?

Comment: Here's an example Q/A where installing a RHEL7 package fails on RHEL8: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/652010/receiving-an-error-when-trying-to-install-git-on-rhel8-box#comment1223884_652010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not officially supported by Red Hat.

As outlined on [this page](https://access.redhat.com/articles/54483):

***Can I install RHEL 7 packages on my RHEL 8,RHEL 6 or RHEL 5 system?***

***No.*** Manual installation of RHEL X packages on RHEL Y systems (where X ≠ Y) is not supported by Red Hat. The installation of packages across major releases is not supported.

---

That being said, it is technically possible, but things might break.

Try this:

```bsh
sudo dnf downgrade --releasever=7 <package-name>.
```

Alternatively, you could download the desired package and perform a local install on it using DNF:

```bsh
sudo dnf install /path/to/package.rpm
```